# There is vs there are?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> There **is** the brother and the sister

vs

> There **are** the brother and the sister

If they were brother**s** and sister**s** would it be **is** or **are**?

Comment: There are two of them, yes?  So it should be plural.  But you'll find that when you have grammar problems like this, it's an awkward sentence and should be rephrased.  "The brother and the sister are over there." perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Giving this question a formal answer by using Andrew's answer.

> There are two of them, yes? So it should be plural. But you'll find that when you have grammar problems like this, it's an awkward sentence and should be rephrased. "The brother and the sister are over there."