# "there is/are not only one but many ..."

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I have a sentence along the lines of

> There is/are not only one, but many of these synchrotron radiation sources
> around the world.

So I have to decide between *is* and *are*. I have the feeling that I have seen this question discussed before, but I fail to google a suitable phrase to get an answer.

Comment: The question was discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203418/there-is-vs-there-are). you can always search the site yourself.

Comment: The question you linked is fairly trivial example of two singular nouns in a list. As I have a conjunction in my sentence, I thought that a different rule may apply. But thinking about it a bit more, the same rule should probably be applied here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "There is not only one but many" is the right option.

Here are some uses from professional publications.

> Since, in general, there **is** not only one but many level dependent
> capacities compatible with the preference information provided
> by the Decision Maker, we propose to take into account all of
> them by using the Robust Ordinal Regression (ROR) and the
> Stochastic Multicriteria Acceptability Analysis (SMAA).
>
> — [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221719306447) (with added emphasis)

> Ms Ghilaine: There **is** not only one but many difficulties, and they
> are mutually reinforcing.
>
> — [Trial International](https://trialinternational.org/judicial-body/the-appellate-court-of-bukavu/) (with added emphasis)

The reason is that, in such cases, the verb must agree with the **nearest noun**.